# É possível fazer com CSS um simbolo de infinito com um circulo passando por dentro de outro?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer essa forma. ***Repare como um círculo parece passar por dentro do outro...***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem não estou conseguindo fazer um elemento "passar por dentro do outro" com CSS, é possível chegar nessa forma apenas CSS? Tipo dois arcos entrelaçados?

Segue até onde consegui chegar.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid tomato;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.box.y {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box x"></div>
<div class="box y"></div>
```

Comment: Mas tu também nunca facilita né?! Tô só esperando a edição da pergunta adicionando a frase "Sem SVG por favor"

Comment: @fernandosavio quer moleza? Senta no pudim! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Com `::before` e `::after` apenas na primeira div você consegue:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}

.box, .box.x::before, .box.x::after {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid tomato;
}

.box.x::before, .box.x::after{
   content: '';
   top: -20px;
}

.box.x::before{
   left: -20px;
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
   z-index: inherit;
}

.box.x, .box.x::after{
   box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.box.x::after{
   left: 80px;
   border-top-color: transparent;
}

.box.x {
   z-index: 20;
} 

.box.y {
   left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box x"></div>
   <div class="box y"></div>
</div>
```

A ideia é que a `div.x` tenha um z-index maior do que a `div.y` e o `::before` fique por cima com a borda inferior transparente para que a borda do `::after` passe por cima. A mesma coisa com o `::after`, só que com a borda superior transparente.

A sombra (`box-shadow`) apliquei somente na `div.x` e no seu `::after`, porque, como o `::after` fica por cima da `div.y`, essa div não precisa da sombra.

### Questão da sombra

Tive que criar um pseudo `::before` na `div.y` e alterar a sombra para `inset` na pseudo `::before` da `div.x` e usar duas sombras, uma `inset` e outra `outset` (padrão) na pseudo `::after` da `div.x`:

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}

.box, .box.x::before, .box.x::after, .box.y::before{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid tomato;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.box.x::before, .box.x::after, .box.y::before{
   content: '';
   top: -20px;
}

.box.x::before{
   left: -20px;
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
   z-index: inherit;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.box.x, .box.x::after{
   box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.box.x::after{
   left: 80px;
   border-top-color: transparent;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.box.y::before{
   left: -20px;
   z-index: 20;
   border-top-color: transparent;
}

.box.x {
   z-index: 20;
} 

.box.y {
   left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box x"></div>
   <div class="box y"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom Sam chegou a 90%, só que o elemento tem uma sombra total, tipo para todos os lados, repara la na intercessão das imagens e repara como é a sombra entre os elementos

Comment: Na sombra do seu exemplo do código só tem sombra pra fora.

Comment: +1. Acho que é só mudar as sombras pra dar impressão que está em cima: `.box.x { box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) inset }` `.box.x::after { box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) }`: https://i.imgur.com/AouI9Jc.png

Comment: Sim Sam, não tem porque eu não consegui fazer. Mas a intenção é deixar igual a imagem de referência como eu comentei na pergunta. É um detalhe que ao meu ver faz diferença, pois da mais profundidade no "entrelaçado" dos elementos. A intenção como falei era chegar na forma da imagem, como eu não consegui chegar lá deixei a pergunta aqui.... apesar disso ficou muito bom, como já tinha falado.

Comment: @hugocsl Adicionei na resposta. Abs!

Comment: Ta vendo, não era tão difícil ;) vlw

Comment: @Renan Valeu! Consegui com uma sombra inset :D

Comment: Estou impressionado com suas skills, ficou ótimo.